# OneSignal Notification Extension, error Could not find any available provisioning profiles

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, onesignal

Forms project I created an notification extension for ios as said from https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/xamarin-sdk-setup at step 5. And then I applied these steps at https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/provisioning/working-with-capabilities/app-groups-capabilities/ .

But I have the error

> Could not find any available provisioning profiles.

How can I solve this situation?

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old post but I am posting the answer to help others.

After following all the instructions I had the same issue. I solved it by updating my certificates, identifiers, and profile.

The first thing I did was to create an Apps Group Identifier in Identifiers section of developer portal (Note that your identifier name should be "group.{your_bundle_id}.onesignal" and this should be the same in your Xamarin.iOS Entitlements.plist of App group)

Go to the Identifier and enable App Groups and added the App Group Identifier.

After doing that update all your certificates and provisional profile with your newly updated identifier then add it to your keychain access.

After that, I changed my Bundle Signing settings in Xamairn.iOS to Automatic Provisioning and then selected my team.

If you cannot select your team then go tools -> Options -> Xamarin -> Apple Accounts. click on add.

I hope this was helpful and if my answer helped you give it a thumbs up.

Answer (score -1):

If you want use  `notification` in your app.Don't forget to Make sure to select Explicit App ID and that the Bundle Identifier doesn't end with a * . This will create an identifier that is good for multiple applications, and push notification certificates must be for a single application.
[image]

> And under App Services, select Push Notifications:

[image]

> In your project->Entitlements.plist

[image]